# Select and clear contents of an unspecified cell range in newly copy and pasted worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, button, range, copy-paste

I am trying to achieve the following:

- I have a VBA button that when clicked, copies the active worksheet and pastes it into a new worksheet (I have this function already working perfectly - see code below).
- I then want the newly pasted worksheet to find two specified cells, which contain the texts ("bus start") and ("bus finish") and clear all the contents in the cells that are in between the range of the two specified cells.

The rows are dynamic and will change over time as rows get added and deleted, hence why I cannot define a fixed range. Columns however, will not be deleted or added and therefore will be fixed.

For reference, here is my copy and paste code:

```
Private Sub WkCapBtn_Click()

Dim Ws1 As Worksheet

Set Ws1 = ActiveSheet

    Ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = DateAdd("d", 7, ActiveSheet.Range("C3"))
            ActiveSheet.Name = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value, ("dd-mmm-yy"))

End Sub
```

My initial thinking was to use a .Find function to locate the specified cells and then use a .Offset to select the cells below and above. Where I am stuck though is actually trying to define the range between the specified cells.

If any additional information is needed, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does `Range(rBusStart.Offset(1, 0), rBusFinish.Offset(-1, 0)).EntireRow.ClearContents` do it for you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code works, but it clears the entire row. I can't have it clearing the first 3 columns (I was hoping the column offset would work, but it doesn't). Is there something I can change to prevent it clearing the first 3 columns?

Comment: Also, it is clearing the contents of the old sheet which I have copied the data over from. I need it to clear the newly made sheet. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all, are you sure that your newly created workbook gets renamed and not the original? Why do you set ws = ActiveSheet when you then use the activesheet for the new worksheet? I believe your problem starts with this.

Comment: At the time I was receiving an error for object not defined. Defining Ws1 as an activesheet seemed to solve the issue. When the code executes, it does successfully rename the newly made sheet, which then becomes the activesheet. The old one is left as it is.

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone. Chris, your code did the trick after I played around with it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code a little for the beginning:

```
Static WsCopy As Worksheet
Static Ws1 As Worksheet

Private Sub WkCapBtn_Click()

    Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORIGINALSHEETNAME")

    Set WSCopy = Ws1.Copy After:=(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    With WSCopy
        .Name = Format(.Range("A1").Value, ("dd-mmm-yy"))
        .Range("C3").Value = DateAdd("d", 7, .Range("C3"))
    End With
End Sub
```

For your other sub you could set a variable for the cells containing either "bus start" or "bus finish". Can you try the following code and tell me if it worked?

```
Private Sub DelBusRange()

    Dim BusStart As Range
    Dim BusFinish As Range

    With WsCopy
        Set BusStart = .Find(What:="Bus start", _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

        Set BusFinish = .Find(What:="Bus finish", _
                         After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                         LookIn:=xlValues, _
                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                         MatchCase:=False)

        .Range(BusStart, BusFinish).clear
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

For the first part, it is giving a syntax error at 'Set WSCopy = Ws1.Copy After:=(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count))'. Also, I can't define the worksheet name as each week a new worksheet is made with a different name, hence why originally I was using "Activesheet". I will try the second section of code.

Comment: The second section of your code only executes up to the BusStart setting, where it then provides an overflow error. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's all good, I have figured it out! Thank you for your help, much appreciated. Chir Neilsen's code in the previous comments required some changes

Answer (score 0):

Chris Neilson's code did the trick once I changed it around.

```
Private Sub WkCapBtn_Click()

Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Dim FindBus1 As String
Dim FindBus2 As String
Dim BusMatch1 As Range
Dim BusMatch2 As Range

Set Ws1 = ActiveSheet

    Ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = DateAdd("d", 7, ActiveSheet.Range("C3"))
            ActiveSheet.Name = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value, ("dd-mmm-yy"))

        FindBus1 = "Bus Start"

        FindBus2 = "Bus Finish"
        Set BusMatch1 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(FindBus1)
        Set BusMatch2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(FindBus2)

        ActiveSheet.Range(BusMatch1.Offset(3, 1), BusMatch2.Offset(-2, 1)).ClearContents


End Sub
```